# c: realloc(): invalid pointer

Tags: c, malloc, realloc, strcpy

my question is simple, the code shows the problem:

this works

```c
   char *str1;
   str1 = (char *) malloc(3);
   strcpy(str1, "hi"); 
   printf("%s\n", str1);

   str1 = realloc(str1, 5); 
   strcpy(str1, "hi ho");
   printf("%s\n", str1);
```

this not, why?

```c
   char *str2;
   str2 = (char *) malloc(3);
   str2 = "hi";            // not using strcpy
   printf("%s\n", str2);

   str2 = realloc(str2, 5); 
   str2 = "hi ho";         // not using strcpy
   printf("%s\n", str2);
```

terminal output:

```
hi
hi ho
hi
realloc(): invalid pointer
```

edit:
so is the Segmentation fault in this programm the same type of error?

```c
int main() {
   char * s_test = malloc(3);
   s_test = "ho";
   printf("s: %s", s_test);
   // should we free now ? 
   free(s_test); // segmentation fault core dumped
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `str2 = "hi";` doesn't do what you think it does..

Comment: wow , what a short and precise answer-.- ...

Comment: The `malloc` assignment makes `str2` point to some dynamically allocated memory. The `str2 = "hi";` makes it point to a read-only section containing that hard-coded string. The reference to the dynamically allocated memory is "lost" and is never freed. The `realloc` call is invalid because the hard-coded "hi" string was never dynamically allocated.